# AuthHost disallowed UrlAction: 0x2301

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, windows-8.1, azure-active-directory

Below is log from the windows event viewer. Anyone knows why it is disallowed?

AuthHost disallowed UrlAction: 0x2301 for URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri=xxxx&state=12345&nonce=678910&resource=https://graph.windows.net/.

Comment: Were you using [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)? If not please check whether [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acff0466-1ed1-49a2-90ae-6dc0a6bb0e98/authhost-encountered-a-navigation-error?forum=WindowsAzureAD) is helpful. And if you still have this issue, please share a piece of code which could reproduce this issue.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT No I'm not using ADAl.js as it's only for web application. In my case I have a native app and I'm using "Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync" to perform AAD login.
The link you shared does not help in this case as I have the correct redirect uri.

Comment: I am failed to reproduce this issue on Window 10. Are you able to using the `WebAuthenticationBroker‌​.authenticateAsync` to navigate other web pages?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why I'm facing the disallow error that is, in the option of the "authenticateAsync" method, I should use "useCorporateNetwork" instead of "none".